# filter out elements of a vector in clojure that cannot be parsed into numbers

Tags: clojure

Consider the following vector in clojure:

```
(def v ["aaa" "1" "2" "ko" "bla"])
```

One way to do that is:

```
(defn keep-numbers [v]
  (filter number?
      (map (fn [itm]
             (let [num (try (read-string itm) (catch Exception e nil))] num)
             ) v)))
```

This produces the following result:

```
(1 2)
```

Is there any way to do that and get rid of the try catch block?

Comment: It's best to use specialized methods like `Integer/parseInt` and `Double/parseDouble` to parse numbers, not a generic `parse-string`.

Comment: Catching the exception may be the best way.  Solutions based on regular expressions can get very complicated, depending on how you are defining "number".  For example, Clojure numbers can look like 42, 42.0,  2r101010, 8r52, 36r16, 42N, or 42.0M; This makes solutions based on regular expressions more complicated than one might think at first.

Answer (score 4):

You could use regular expressions to filter valid inputs first:

```clj
(->> v
     (filter (partial re-matches #"\d"))
     (map read-string))
```

The same using `Integer/parseInt`:

```clj
(->> v
     (filter (partial re-matches #"\d"))
     (map #(Integer/parseInt %)))
```

The same using single `for` loop instead of `filter` and `map` higher-order functions:

```clj
(for [el v :when (re-matches #"\d" el)]
  (Integer/parseInt el))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do

```
(filter (comp number? clojure.edn/read-string) ["aaa" "1" "2" "ko" "bla"])
```

Map over this if you also want to parse.